# Collision detection in Python(pygame)

Tags: pygame

I have been wondering how collision detection works, I have had many attempts, but can't get it to work. I am new to pygame, so if anyone is kind enough to read this, please can you add the correct lines to my code as well as explaining it. If anyone was wondering what this code did, it has 2 racecars thatare trying to hit a football and move it in the direction the car is hitting it at(I was thinking a possible way to complete this was to check the angle the car is rotated at, and move the ball by that amount, - 180 degrees to move it forward)

Thank you very much

```
import pygame
from pygame.math import Vector2


pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1150, 800))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()  
BLUECAR_ORIGINAL = pygame.Surface((100, 30), pygame.SRCALPHA)
pygame.draw.polygon(
    BLUECAR_ORIGINAL, (0, 0, 255), [(0, 0), (50, 10), (50, 20), (0, 30)])
bluecar = BLUECAR_ORIGINAL

REDCAR_ORIGINAL = pygame.Surface((50, 30), pygame.SRCALPHA)
pygame.draw.polygon(
    REDCAR_ORIGINAL, (200, 0, 0), [(0, 0), (50, 10), (50, 20), (0, 30)])
redcar = REDCAR_ORIGINAL

ball = pygame.draw.circle(screen, [255,255,255],[60,60],5)






pos = Vector2(70, 70)  
vel = Vector2(7, 0)

poss = Vector2(70,70)
vell = Vector2(7,0)

redrect = redcar.get_rect(center=pos)
redangle = 0  

bluerect = bluecar.get_rect(center=pos)
blueangle = 0


run = True
while run:
ball = pygame.draw.circle(screen, [0,0,0],[575,400],30)
pygame.display.flip()
for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
        run = False




keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
if keys[pygame.K_LEFT]:

    redangle += 5
    vel.rotate_ip(-5)
    redcar = pygame.transform.rotate(REDCAR_ORIGINAL, redangle)

    redrect = redcar.get_rect(center=pos)
elif keys[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
    redangle -= 5
    vel.rotate_ip(5)
    redcar = pygame.transform.rotate(REDCAR_ORIGINAL, redangle)
    redrect = redcar.get_rect(center=pos)


if keys[pygame.K_a]:
    blueangle += 5
    vell.rotate_ip(-5)
    bluecar = pygame.transform.rotate(BLUECAR_ORIGINAL, blueangle)
    bluerect = bluecar.get_rect(center=pos)
elif keys[pygame.K_d]:
    blueangle -= 5
    vell.rotate_ip(5)
    bluecar = pygame.transform.rotate(BLUECAR_ORIGINAL, blueangle)
    bluerect = bluecar.get_rect(center=poss)

hits = pygame.sprites.groupcollide(bluecar, ball, False, False)
hits = pygame.sprites.spritecollide(bluecar, ball, False)


pos += vel
redrect.center = pos  

poss += vell
bluerect.center = poss

bgImg = pygame.image.load("Football_pitch.png")
screen.blit(bgImg, (0,0))

screen.blit(redcar, redrect)

screen.blit(bluecar, bluerect)




pygame.display.flip()
clock.tick(60)  
pygame.quit()
```

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways:
you could save the coordinates of each sprite as variables and then compare the coordinates of both sprites to each other than do whatever you need to when they are close enough, for example:

```
if object1_X <= object2_X+5 and object1_X>= object2_X-5 and object1_Y<= object2_Y+5 and object1_Y>=object2_X-5:
    #do something
    #all that above basically is just saying if the objects above are within a 10-pixel radius of each other do something
    pass
```

or you could use the distance formula:

```
distance=((object2_X-object1_X)**2+(object2_Y-object1_Y)**2)**0.5
if distance <= 10:
    #do something
    pass
```

which utilises the Pythagorean theorem to find the distance between two objects

or you could use pygame's existing function:

```
object1=pygame.draw.rect(screen,color,[x,y1,50,30],0)
object2=pygame.draw.rect(screen,colorb,[x2,y2,7,7],0)
if object1.colliderect(object2):
    #do something
    pass
```

if you were wondering how it works, I am not 100% sure but it likely uses one of the two rudimentary methods internally to calculate this